# Delphi DFM not found

Tags: delphi, dfm

I am having one xyz.pas file reference in my project. But that file is not with me. I am having the xyz.dcu and xyz.obj file of that xyz.pas file.
When I tried to compile the project I have got the Error "xyz.dcu not found". So i have included the path of xyz.dcu in Search path. Now I am getting error "xyz.dfm not found".

Please suggest me the solution. Is it possible to compile the project with only .dcu and .obj files?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Naren

Answer (score 7):

I hope you haven't lost your work.

Simplified, Delphi works like this:
PAS+DFM => DCU
DCU+RES => EXE
More about Delphi files at the end of this answer.

You can compile the project if you only have the DCU file. First, remove the PAS file from your folder else Delphi will try to recompile it (and in order to recompile it, it needs the DFM file).
I don't think the Obj file will be of any use to you.

---

The DFM file is very very important for your project but yet not critical important. If you are in deep need, you can still go on without it as it can be reconstructed manually based on information you have in the PAS file and based on the way the application's GUI looks (if you have ever seen it running).

Here is the trick (involves some work):

Just create a new form and then look at the top of your original PAS file for the declaration of the form. It may look like this:

```
TYPE
  TYourForm = class(TForm)
     xLabel: TLabel;
     yButton: TButton;
     etc
     etc
  end;
```

Then put all those controls back to your new form and name them exactly as they are named in the PAS file (xLabel, yButton, etc). Arrange them to resemble the original GUI. When done, replace the new created PAS file with your original PAS file. IMPORTANT: the name of the DFM and PAS file should match. Compile and you are done! The rebuilt GUI may not look EXACTLY as the original one, but it should do it.

**Hint:

There are tools that can extract the DFM file from DCU/EXE.

Here are some of them: www.delphi2.software.informer.com/download-delphi-extract-dfm

This will help you a lot!**

---

.PAS - Delphi Source File
PAS should be stored in Source Control
In Delphi, PAS files are always the source code to either a unit or a form. Unit source files contain most of the code in an application. The unit contains the source code for any event handlers attached to the events of the form or the components it contains. We may edit .pas files using Delphi's code editor. Do not delete .pas files.

.DCU - Delphi Compiled Unit
A compiled unit (.pas) file. By default the compiled version of each unit is stored in a separate binary-format file with the same name as the unit file, but with the extension .DCU (Delphi compiled unit). For example unit1.dcu contains the code and data declared in the unit1.pas file. When you rebuild a project, individual units are not recompiled unless their source (.PAS) files have changed since the last compilation, or their .DCU files cannot be found. Safely delete .dcu file because Delphi recreates it when you compile the application.

.DFM - Delphi Form
DFM should be stored in Source Control
These files are always paired with .pas files. Dfm file contains the details (properties) of the objects contained in a form. It can be view as text by right clicking on the form and selecting view as text from the pop-up menu. Delphi copies information in .dfm files into the finished .exe code file. Caution should be used in altering this file as changes to it could prevent the IDE from being able to load the form. Form files can be saved in either binary or text format. The Environment Options dialog lets you indicate which format you want to use for newly created forms. Do not delete .dfm files.

source: delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/aa032800a.htm

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for help. U gave me some hopes to build the project. Someone deleted the xyz.pas and xyz.dfm file from my project. And now i m having copy of xyz.dcu only. Now as dont have xyz.pas, why I am getting error "xyz.dfm not found"? please suggest solution to compile the project. Thanks a lot again.   --- Naren

Comment: `You can compile the project if you only have the DCU file.`This is only correct if you're using the **exact** same version of Delphi that the original .dcu was created with (note the emphasis on **exact**). Otherwise, you have to have the .pas file to recompile for the different version of Delphi.

Comment: DFM aren't contained in the DCUs. DFM are essentially special *.RES file. If you don't have the DFM file, you can't use the DCU to compile.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still in the possesion of the executable, then you can extract your complete and original DFM file from the application resources by any arbitrary resource manager. For example: [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi_2006.htm). In the RC DATA category, there will be an item called TXYZ.

Comment: hi, thanks. I just want to compile the project successfully. Is it possible to compile with dcu files only? --- Naren

Comment: I just tried, but didn't work. Maybe this only works when the dfm is stored binary. But: Do you have the (old) executable?

Comment: bad luckily i dont have the old exe also. :(

Answer (score 2):

**Delphi 20xx/XE**
Note that Delphi saves old versions of your files in a hidden subdir of your project dir called `__history`.

In that dir are saved versions of your .pas, .dfm and other project files.
These files are created every time you save a change to disk.

Do a search on your harddisk for all files, (including hidden ones) named `*.~*~` this should bring up any backup source files you may have.
They will miss the last change(s) you made, but at least you will not have to do everything all over again.

**Delphi 7 and before**
Delphi 7 saves these files in the same dir as your project files with a `.~` extension.

Answer (score 1):

DFM-Files hold the "visual" aspects (controls, components, properties, visuals, data...) of a (say) form. If the PAS-File (or the compiled DCU-File) needs the DFM, you have to have it, or you get this error. There is no other way than to have the DFM, i think.

Correction (as written below, sorry!): you **can** compile with only the DCU-file if you remove the PAS-file and provide **ONLY** the DCU-File. In this case the DCU-File must be compiled with the same compiler-version to be linked into the App, because the compiler can not recompile the DCU.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late, but here's what I came with.

My directory stucture is like this

```
/ Project
  / Source
    / Unit1.pas
  / Packages
    /Delphi2010Berlin
      / MyPackage1.dpk
      / MyPackage2.dpk
  / Library
    / Delphi2010Berlin
      / Win32
        / Debug
        / Release
```

In the /Project folder, i created a .bat file named 'dfmcopy.bat'

All it contains is

```
@echo off
for /r %1 %%x in (*.dfm) do @copy "%%x" %2 /Y >NUL
```

Then, in my post build event for my .bpl

```
./../../dfmcopy.bat $(PROJECTPATH)\..\..\Source $(PROJECTPATH)\..\..\Library\$(Platform)\$(Config)
```

This will recursively copy all .dfm that are contained in the /Source folder into the /Library/{DelphiVersion}/{Platform}/{Config} folder

One caveat is that if you have multiple projects that have this post build event, dfms might be copied over and over for each project. Don't know if that can pose any issue now.

Answer (score -1):

I use apache ant  to build  delphi project.

I fix the "dfm not found error" by  deleting all dcu files   and seperating compiler  output files from source files.

The problem is probabily caused by wrong  path of dcus files.

```
   <project name ="app1" default = "run">


<property name="delphipath" value="your delphi path"/>

<property name="source" value="C:/ws4d/TStateMachine-master/Tests"/>
<property name="dunit" value="C:/ws4d/dunit-svn"/>

<property name="DCUOUT" value="C:/ws4d/TStateMachine-master/Tests/BIN"/>

<target name="run">
  <!-- Compile with Delphi 6 -->
  <apply executable="${delphipath}/bin/dcc32.exe" failonerror="true" output="build-dxe10.log" >
    <!-- rebuild quiet -->
    <arg value="-B"/>
    <arg value="-Q"/>
    <!-- file paths -->
    <arg value="-I${source};{dunit}/src"/>

    <arg value="-U${source};{dunit}/src;{delphipath}/lib/win32/release"/>
    <arg value="-R${source};{dunit}/src;{delphipath}/lib/win32/release"/>

    <arg value="-O${DCUOUT};"/>
    <arg value="-N${DCUOUT}"/>
    <arg value="-E${DCUOUT}"/>
    <!-- all *.dpr files in current directory -->
    <fileset dir=".">
      <patternset><include name="*.dpr"/></patternset>
    </fileset>
  </apply>
</target>


</project>
```